# How to sort only subset in std::vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a `vector` of `pair`s:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Cell::Ptr>> mCells;
```

I want to sort only a subset of elements (on the `first`'s `string`).  The `Cell` has method `GetSorted()` which indicates if it's part of this subset or not.

This is what I had initially:

```
std::sort(mCells.begin(), mCells.end(),
          [](std::pair<std::string, Cell::Ptr> const &a,
             std::pair<std::string, Cell::Ptr> const &b)
{
    // Only compare when both cells need to be sorted; otherwise return false
    // to indicate that they are already in correct order.  This keeps the
    // non-marked cells at their original positions.
    if (a.second->GetSorted() && b.second->GetSorted())
    {
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

But it does not work, because `sort`, of course, does not compare all combinations.  Sometimes the `return a.first < b.first` line is not even executed once.

To define the required sort function, here's an example.  Suppose the elements are:

```
G* F  C* A* D  B  E*
```

Only the *-ones need to be sorted.  But, the sort should only be applied to adjacent to-be-sorted elements.  (That's why I had `a.second->GetSorted() && b.second->GetSorted()`.)  The result should then be:

```
G* F  A* C* D  B  E*
```

So, only **A** and **C** are adjacent, and are sorted.  Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Alternatively a solution that results in:

```
A* F  C* E* D  B  G*
```

would also be usable for me at the moment.  So, sorting all * elements, while leaving the others where they are.  This appears to be easier to do.

Comment: How do you intend to identify the starred elements for your sorting ?

Comment: Is it acceptable to traverse the range, identifying valid ranges and sorting those?

Comment: @DumbCoder Read the third line of my post.

Comment: @pmr The number of elements is no more than 20, so yes (assuming you were thinking of performance).

Comment: @meaning-matters so you have a vector of pairs, and you only want to sort *some* of them relative to each other, leaving the others untouched? I don't see that happening without a temporary sort bed of some kind (and even then, it won't be trivial). If they're adjacent exclusively you can do it with restricted iterators, but if they're not....

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed.  Is MartinJ's solution what you're thinking of?

Comment: @meaning-matters pretty close, It will sort segments of adjacent elements, but I don't see it sorting the *entire* sequence via selection. I.e. suppose your sorting only odd numbers,and our sequence is `{5,1,2,8,7,3,4,9,6}`. From your description I would expect the result to be `{1,3,2,8,5,7,4,9,6}`, I.e. all the odds are sorted but the evens are untouched. The selected solution will not do that to that extent (or if it does, I certainly don't see how intuitively).

Comment: @WhozCraig I wanted to sort only adjacent elements, which MartinJ's solution does.  I don't know what you mean with "odds are sorted".

Comment: @meaning-matters look at the two lists in my prior comment, then look at what happened to all the odd numbers (1,3,5,7, etc) vs the evens. As I said, if sorting only numbers that are pas the to-be-sorted litmus test *and* are strictly adjacent to each other, the selected algorithm will work. If you want to sort specific numbers across the entire sequence *regardless of adjacency* as was done in the sample of my prior comment, then it isn't enough. I honestly cannot explain it better than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate finding the ranges to be sorted and sorting them:

```
using namespace std;

auto isSorted = [](std::pair<std::string, Cell::Ptr> const &a) {
    return a.second->GetSorted();
}

auto it = begin(mCells);
const auto itEnd = end(mCells);
while (it != itEnd) {
    auto rangeStart = find_if(it, itEnd, isSorted);
    if (rangeStart == itEnd)
        break; 
    auto rangeEnd = find_if_not(rangeStart, itEnd, isSorted);
    if (distance(rangeStart, rangeEnd) > 1) { 
        // pair comparison should do the trick here
        sort(rangeStart, rangeEnd); 
    }
    it = rangeEnd;
}
```

---

Just saw your edit: you can achieve the alternate solution by defining a custom input iterator class that skips non-sorted elements, then using a single sort() call on the whole "range".

Comment: +1 the custom input iterator skipping non-sorted elements is a *wonderful* idea.